# Selecting data from Google App Engine datastore by field value

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm just staring off with GAE. So like many I'm used to standard SQL.

Typically when you want to select data that has a certain field value you use:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <column> = <wanted value>
```

Is the correct way to do this in GAE

```
<Model Class>.all().filter('<column> =', <wanted value>)
```

Or is there a more efficient way?

**EDIT:** Also I should note in this particular case I only want one result returned. So is there another command so that it doesn't keep looking after if finds a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is pretty close to what you're looking for - it constructs a [Query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) object which can be used to query the datastore.  To actually get a result, you'll need to execute the query.  To get a single result, you'll want to use the [`get()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_get) method:

```
result = <Model Class>.all().filter('<column> =', <wanted value>).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [Model.gql](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_gql)('where column = :value', value=something) which returns a `GqlQuery` upon which a [GqlQuery.get()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_get) returns a single item.